# problem with firebase auth when i added to pubspec.yaml

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Parameter format not correct -

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':firebase_core:javaPreCompileDebug'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':firebase_core:debugCompileClasspath'.
  >   Could not find firebase-common.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.1.0).
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-common/16.1.0/firebase-common-16.1.0.jar
  >   Could not find legacy-support-v4.jar (androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0).
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/legacy/legacy-support-v4/1.0.0/legacy-support-v4-1.0.0.jar
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin firebase_auth...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'firebase_auth'.

  > SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

Exception: The plugin firebase_auth could not be built due to the issue above.

Answer (score 0):

add following line in gradle.properties

android.useAndroidX=true

Comment: can you send your both build.gradle files here

Comment: Try upgrading gms service to 4.3.3 , which I think is the latest . Use flutter clean before running app again

Answer (score 0):

```
build.gradle
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "co.test.bubbleapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

}

___________________________________

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```